# Android Development: Where to start?

Tags: android

I see a lot of questions about it, a lot of different answers here and there, but nothing past 2014.

I would like to start building apps on Android (we'll see for iOS later). I am home, I have a lot of time, I don't want to spend too much money (I am ok for a subscription around $30/month to whatever platform or buying a book here and there) but basically: **Where do I start?**

If you could tell me the path you would choose, knowing the advanced state of Android and all resources available nowadays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should deal with the advance stuffs later and focus on the fundamentals. If you already know java, then you already have a jumpstart. For android development, the topics that (for me) you should be playing around would be:

- Activity Life Cycle.
- MultiThreading
- Image Processes
- Google Material Design (this may come later on but the basic design principles should
  be learned).

I recommend O'Reilly's Head First Android Development.

When you learned the basics, you should be able to follow through more advanced stuffs.

EDIT:

Java has been out for decades already, so there should be no problems finding tutorials for it. There are lots of tutorials available starting from ebooks to youtube tutorials. A Head first book I have found may be helpful when starting to learn the language. It is also encouraged that you get familiar with Object Oriented Programming for you will mostly deal with it on android. I'll recommend gaining familiarity with:

- Arrays
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism

You have a long way to go, but once you get familiar with the basics you'll be good to go for android.

Comment: I only used the official tutorial and I do Android development for a living. I also agree with the topics suggested by @MetaSnarf.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I do not know Java, so maybe I should actually start by this, what do you suggest on that particular point ?

Comment: Editted my answer @FrenchyNYC

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are a beginner . and i will suggest answer according to this.

1. The first thing you need for android development is being good in java or your base programming language. You dont have to be best in it but have a good touch on it.
2. In java topics you should be aware of are mainly-

   Inheritance , scope assignment to variables , access specifiers , error handling , looping , data types and basic knowledge of database query.

   i am suggesting these topics as these are few things which will make you comfortable in android and make it easy for you.
3. The best place to start your android training is from the official website of android. this is the best place for all the knowledge. but as you are beginner you will have difficult time getting these concepts. so i suggest you first go through some youtube videos . even if you dont get it first after sometimes this will make sense. and after sometime you will get a basic knowledge for android. then you can go through many blogs and the website to gain more and more knowledge. once you are comfortable with the basics you will have no problem going further.
4. During doing any blog reading or video watching dont only watch or read it , make your own practice with it. because as a programming language you never know when you make mistake unless you do it yourself.

These are some links to follow-

[official website](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

[new boston youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL023BC9408BAFEC0C)

[slidenerd youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa)

[vogella blog](http://www.vogella.com/)

[tutsplus](http://tutsplus.com/)

[androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/)

be persistent . thats the only key. good luck.

Comment: I like the fact that YouTube is full of great things ! Thank you for these links that I bookmarked !

Comment: hey @FrenchyNYC can you accept my answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.udacity.com/courses/android

Udecity android courses are official android course designed and conducted by google developers.

it will teach you step by step app developent with very interesting real life examples.

course is not free but course material like Videos and sample codes are free. 
i think you will not need to subscribe for paid course.

Udecity's Android course material will be far better.

All the best my Bro.

Comment: Resource that indeed, I didn't know ! Thank you very much bro ! I won't disappoint you ;)